# How to get libraries which i have installed using QPYPI in the file manager of Android

Tags: python, qpython

Am having a problem in getting the libraries such as kivy which i have installed through QPYPI. How can i get them since when i navigate to */ qpython/ lib/ python2.7/ site-packages/* the folder is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your site packages aren't stored in the qpython folder especially if you are not using an external sdcard

On my phone all libraries are stored in 
"/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages" path

If you cant access this path on your phone ,then you need to root your phone

Comment: Thanks so much so i need to uninstall qpython and insert a sd card and install the libraries so that i can manipulate them ?

Comment: Nope, qpython itself can access its own files! Just write a script to copy out "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages"!